# Hide StackOverflow Question Footer?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

Hello;

Is it proper that when you are logged in to StackOverflow, and looking at a question, at the bottom it reads: "Not the answer you're looking for? Browse other questions tagged <some tags>"?

I think this shouldn't appear when you have had activity in that question because it is rather unlikely that you are there because you were looking for the answer to that question...

Comment: Certainly a purely aesthetic change.

Comment: @Nathan Exactly... It will also apply to this very same meta site :)